# Emacs c++ tabs writing spaces removing

Tags: c++, emacs, tabs, key-bindings

I have seen a lot of questions about emacs and tabs/spaces topic but no one talking about this:

I have emacs in C++ mode and tabs as indent character, if i press enter for a newline emacs auto-indent with tab but if i try to remove that "tab" i remove only one space.

I understand that emacs create tabs using spaces but if i want to remove that "tab" i would want to remove the 4 (or 8) spaces directly not one by one, in python-mode works as intended but in c++ mode no. There is a variable for that or any work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Backspace key (`<DEL>`) is probably bound to command `backward-delete-char-untabify`.  Bind it to something else, e.g. `delete-backward-char`.

From the Elisp manual, node [Program Modes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Program-Modes.html):

> In most programming languages, indentation should vary from line to
>   line to illustrate the structure of the program.  Therefore, in most
>   programming language modes, typing `<TAB>` updates the indentation of the
>   current line.
>
> Furthermore, **`<DEL>` is usually
>   bound to `backward-delete-char-untabify`, which deletes backward
>   treating each tab as if it were the equivalent number of spaces**, so that
>   you can delete one column of indentation without worrying whether the
>   whitespace consists of spaces or tabs.

IOW, the behavior you don't like is provided by default in the programming mode you are using.

Actually, if you are in `c++-mode`, `<DEL>` is bound to command `c-electric-backspace`. The doc for that function (`C-h f c-electric-backspace`) tells you:

> **`c-electric-backspace`** is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `cc-cmds.el`.
>
> `(c-electric-backspace ARG)`
>
> Delete the preceding character or whitespace.
>
> If `c-hungry-delete-key` is non-`nil` (indicated by `"/h"` on the mode
>   line) then all preceding whitespace is consumed.  If however a prefix
>   argument is supplied, or `c-hungry-delete-key` is `nil`, or point is
>   inside a literal then the function in the variable
>   **`c-backspace-function`** is called.

And by default it seems that the value of user option `c-backspace-function` (`C-h v`) is ... `backward-delete-char-untabify`.  So you can just customize that option to set it to some other function, such as `delete-backward-char`.  That will change the behavior only for C++ and C modes.